# Live search by custom tag

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, search

Live search:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'custom_type', 'sentence' => 'true' ));
if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>

    <?php endwhile;
```

I created a custom post type *"custom_type"* and 2 taxonomies *"custom_cat"*  (hierarchical = true) for categories and *"custom_tags"* (hierarchical = false) for tags.

I need to create a live search by custom tags.

I tried to set *'taxonomy'=>'custom_tags'* but this parameter was ignored and search returned all *"custom_type"* posts by keyword.
Does anyone know solution?

Comment: When you tried to set `'taxonomy'=>'custom_tags'`, did you add it just like that to the `WP_Query` arguments array? Or did you try it like `'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy'  => 'custom_tags' ) )`?

Answer (score 0):

`'post_type' => 'custom_type'` is a reference to your post type.

You need to change `custom_type` to the actual post type that you created / registered.

So, if your post type was my_cool_dregs then the line would be:

```
'post_type' => 'my_cool_dregs'
```

The same holds true with `'taxonomy'=>'custom_tags'`

You need use the actual taxonomy name that you registered.  If your taxonomy was my_dreg_types then that line would be:

```
'taxonomy'=>'my_dreg_types'
```

Comment: I know that. I wrote 'custom_tags', 'custom_type' and 'custom_cat' for example

Comment: Clearly that's not how you wrote it in your code above. Or did you actually name your custom_post_type "custom_type"??